# MacBook Pro: Using Fn key to select the next input sources

Tags: macbook-pro, monterey, keybindings

On my MacBook Pro running Monterey, "control-Space" is assigned to "switch to next input source" (I think this is the default).

When I connect an external Mac keyboard to my MacBook, this works as well. In addititon, the "Fn" key of the external keyboard ALSO cycles to the input sources.

Is there a possibility to have this behaviour too with the builitin MacBook keyboard, i.e. that both "Fn"  and "^-Space" go to the next input source?